# The error parameter in dataWithJSONObject:options:error:

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization

What can happen in the error parameter of

```
+ (NSData *)dataWithJSONObject:(id)obj options:(NSJSONWritingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error
```

It's a class method of the `NSJSONSerialization` class.

The `NSJSONSerialization` class reference specifies that the error contains its value upon return of the method. This would contain a description of the error.  But i don't see what these errors might be, nor do i know how to trigger them. If i try to pull out data from nil or a non valid json object using this method, the app will simply crash while executing this method.

Code example:

```
NSError * error;
request.HTTPBody = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
if (error){
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error); //hier is de error ingevuld mocht er een gebeuren
}
```

I feel like i'm missing/not getting something.

Comment: Can you provide us the crash log

Comment: The proper test for checking `error` would be `if (nil == request.HTTPBody) {`.

Comment: If `dataWithJSONObject` is crashing it's because you're passing it seriously bad data.

Comment: (Show us the crash log.)

Comment: thanks for the comments, i am not confused by the crash, nor by the JSON parsing. I want to know what the error parameter potentially could contain. When will that error not be nil?

Comment: I have the same question. Everything I can do to try to get an error to occur actually just throws an exception. I've tried passing non json objects, tried putting NaN in for numbers. The apple ref doc says "if an internal error occurs".